# Stack swing elements from top to bottom

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout-manager

Consider the following figure:

[image: Required Design]

I need to develop a swing GUI the looks like this. I simply named them jLabel's but there a few images and jLabels in it. The default awt background visible is a JPanel and each red background visible is a serperate JPanel. Now I need them to get stacked as shown above. I tried a number of LayoutManagers and still it doesn't work.

The important point here is that the number of red colored divs are not constant. If there is only one red colored div then it must be displayed at the top, not at the center. As far as i know `GridBagLayout` should work, but it centers the single red colored jpanel available. All the layout managers are centering them but not stacking them from top to bottom.

Comment: I quite didn't get what you meant.The contents of the JPanel are truly dynamic. What is the APPROPRIATE layout manager that does this?? and to top it off the outermost jpanel(the one with awt background) is added to a `JScrollPane`. So `FlowLayout` doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even with anchor set to NORTH then the panels will still be centered. You could work around it by adding a dummy panel to fill the remaining space. Personally I'd stay well away from GridBagLayout though.

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JPanel content = new JPanel();
content.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red));
frame.setContentPane(content);
frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
frame.setSize(400, 300);

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.add(new JLabel("label1"));
    panel.add(new JLabel("label2"));
    panel.add(new JLabel("label3"));
    panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red));
    GridBagConstraints con = new GridBagConstraints();
    con.gridy = i;
    con.gridx = 0;
    con.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
    con.ipady = 10;
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel, con);
}

// dummy panel to use up the space (force others to top)
frame.getContentPane().add(
        new JPanel(),
        new GridBagConstraints(0, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST,
                GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0,
                0));

frame.setVisible(true);
```

GroupLayout example (my favourite layout manager).

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JPanel content = new JPanel();
frame.setContentPane(content);
frame.getContentPane().setLayout(
        new BoxLayout(content, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
frame.setSize(400, 300);
GroupLayout gLayout = new GroupLayout(content);
content.setLayout(gLayout);
ParallelGroup hGroup = gLayout.createParallelGroup();
gLayout.setHorizontalGroup(hGroup);
SequentialGroup vGroup = gLayout.createSequentialGroup();
gLayout.setVerticalGroup(vGroup);
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.add(new JLabel("label1"));
    panel.add(new JLabel("label2"));
    panel.add(new JLabel("label3"));
    panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red));
    hGroup.addComponent(panel);
    vGroup.addComponent(panel, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
            GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE);
    vGroup.addGap(10);
}

frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Is group Layout meant to be for hand coding code??? I stayed away from it all my life... 
And i didn't understand where you inserted this dummy panel?

Comment: @sasidhar Yes GroupLayout can be used "by hand" - having said that a lot of people find it hard to understand. The dummy panel is the one added after the 3 example panels - I've added a comment to the code to point it out.

Answer (score 2):

you can use Vertical BoxLayout, for example:
http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/javax.swing/how-to-use-swing-boxlayout.html

Comment: tried, this does get the first element in the intended position, but when there are only two elements, the next element is expanded to occupy the total remaning place

Comment: Try adding the box layout panel to the north of a panel with a border layout.

Comment: Had the same issue, solved using BoxLayout with Axis=y. thanks Wajdy

Comment: This answer is very unsatisfactory. I couldn't reproduce the image posted by OP using BoxLayout.

Answer (score 2):

nobody tell us that all JComponents must be visible, for example

[image]

[image]

[image]

from code

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class AddComponentsAtRuntime {

    private JFrame f;
    private JPanel panel;
    private JCheckBox checkValidate, checkReValidate, checkRepaint, checkPack;

    public AddComponentsAtRuntime() {
        f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        f.add(panel, "Center");
        f.add(getCheckBoxPanel(), "South");
        f.setLocation(200, 200);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel getCheckBoxPanel() {
        checkValidate = new JCheckBox("validate");
        checkValidate.setSelected(false);
        checkReValidate = new JCheckBox("revalidate");
        checkReValidate.setSelected(false);
        checkRepaint = new JCheckBox("repaint");
        checkRepaint.setSelected(false);
        checkPack = new JCheckBox("pack");
        checkPack.setSelected(false);
        JButton addComp = new JButton("Add New One");
        addComp.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JPanel b = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 4));
                b.setBackground(Color.red);
                b.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black, 2));
                //b.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 20));
                for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                    JLabel l = new JLabel("label" + i + 1);
                    b.add(l);
                    if (i == 2) {
                        l.setVisible(false);
                    }
                }
                panel.add(b);
                makeChange();
                System.out.println(" Components Count after Adds :" + panel.getComponentCount());
            }
        });
        JButton removeComp = new JButton("Remove One");
        removeComp.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int count = panel.getComponentCount();
                if (count > 0) {
                    panel.remove(0);
                }
                makeChange();
                System.out.println(" Components Count after Removes :" + panel.getComponentCount());
            }
        });
        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
        panel2.add(checkValidate);
        panel2.add(checkReValidate);
        panel2.add(checkRepaint);
        panel2.add(checkPack);
        checkPack.setSelected(true);
        panel2.add(addComp);
        panel2.add(removeComp);
        return panel2;
    }

    private void makeChange() {
        if (checkValidate.isSelected()) {
            panel.validate();
        }
        if (checkReValidate.isSelected()) {
            panel.revalidate();
        }
        if (checkRepaint.isSelected()) {
            panel.repaint();
        }
        if (checkPack.isSelected()) {
            f.pack();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AddComponentsAtRuntime makingChanges = new AddComponentsAtRuntime();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you missed a point here, the image i gave you clearly indicates that the height of the background JPanel is fixed and when it increases beyond that point the JScrollPane it is attached to will create scrollbars. using this.pack an creating a JPanel just enough for the components is a trivial solution that doesn't suit my scenario.

Comment: @sasidhar all things around are allways simpler that you thinking about,

Answer (score 1):

You should try the MigLayout it is simple yet powerful. Below I tell miglayout to grow elements, and fill all possible space, then after each element I tell it to go to a new line (wrap). You can find examples and tutorial on MigLayout page http://www.miglayout.com/:

```
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

public class PanelLearning extends JPanel {

public PanelLearning() {
    setLayout(new MigLayout("", "[grow, fill]", ""));

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(new JLabel("label1"));
        panel.add(new JLabel("label2"));
        panel.add(new JLabel("label3"));
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red));
        add(panel, "span, wrap");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Login");
    frame.setVisible(true);

    frame.setContentPane(new PanelLearning());

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.pack();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `GridBagConstraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH` when you add components to the panel.

Comment: tried `GridBagConstraints.NORTH`,`GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START` and also `GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START` nothing seems to work

Comment: @sasidhar Yes I tried NORTH but it didn't work, I had to add a dummy panel to fill the remaining space to force stuff to the top. See my solution.