# I'm adding a combobox to someone's existing Swing code. What am I doing wrong here?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans

```
.addGroup(makeBookingLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel48)
                            .addComponent(sittingPull, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(bookingTime2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
```

I'm trying to place bookingTime2 after sittingPull, to the right. I realise with the current parameters I'm placing them in the same place. I don't understand default_size or preferred_size though. How do I change these parameters to achieve what I want?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: No vertical group? See also this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8504753/230513).

Answer (score 1):

you have (last two code lines in `void` or `contructor`) call for `JComboBox's container`

```
Xxx.revalidate();
Xxx.repaint();
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean?

Comment: [please test how Swing Container works, how LayoutManagers works, what's happened on events add/remove JComponent(s) on runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9675993/714968)

Comment: +1 Useful for dynamic layout, but OP just wants to add the combo to an existing `GroupLayout`.

Comment: @trashgod hard to say something wise but I don't see there something different in compare with rest of Standard LayoutManagers, but required wrote engine by hands, not by Netbeans generated code, I hope that I'm correct...

Comment: @mKorbel: I can't see whether the OP is modifying a horizontal or vertical group, but both are required. The symbol `bookingTime2` is stereotypical of the GUI designer, but OP may not have the corresponding `*.form` file.