# Use an Arraylist as message in JOptionPane.showOptionDialog

Tags: java, user-interface, arraylist, joptionpane

I'm working on a program that changes words by others and I'm trying that the user can change as many words as he wants adding more lines when "add" is pressed. I'll try to explain myself, the program should looks something like this:

[image]

and if I press add:

[image]

if I keep pressing "add" it should adds more and more "lines".

To do that I use this:

```
    JTextField oldword = new JTextField(5);
    JTextField newword = new JTextField(5);
    JPanel Panel = new JPanel();
    List<JPanel> message = new ArrayList<JPanel>();
    String[] options = new String[] {"Ok", "Cancel", "Add", "Delete"};

    Panel.add(new JLabel("Change: "));
    Panel.add(oldword);
    Panel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(15));
    Panel.add(new JLabel("by:"));
    Panel.add(newword);

    message.add(Panel);

    while(response!=0 && response!=1){      
        response = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, message, "Title",
        JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, options, options[0]);
        if(response==2){
          message.add(Panel);
        }
    }
```

But when it gets to "response = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog" I only get a box with this:

[image: Message]

If I press Add it starts repeating that message.

Sorry if I am not clear explaining my problem, I'm quite bad with words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do it, I'm sure it's not the best way to do it but...

```
public String[] setwords(){
    int response=-12;
    String[] options = new String[] {"Ok", "Cancel", "Add", "Delete"};
    JPanel[] panel;
    JTextField[] oldword = null;
    JTextField[] newword = null;

    JTextField[] oldwordaux=null;
    JTextField[] newwordaux=null;
    int size=1;
    Boolean firsttime = true;
    Boolean noword = true;

    String[] words;


    while(response!=0 && response!=JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION && response!=1){
        panel = new JPanel[size];
        oldword = new JTextField[size];
        newword = new JTextField[size];

        for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
            panel[i] = new JPanel();
            oldword[i] = new JTextField(3);
            newword[i] = new JTextField(3);
            panel[i].add(new JLabel("Change: "));
            panel[i].add(oldword[i]);
            panel[i].add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(15));
            panel[i].add(new JLabel("by: "));
            panel[i].add(newword[i]);
            if(firsttime!=true){
                if(i<oldwordaux.length){
                    oldword[i].setText(oldwordaux[i].getText());
                    newword[i].setText(newwordaux[i].getText());
                }
            }
        }
        firsttime = false;
        response = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, panel, "Title", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, options, options[0]);
        if(response==2){
            size++;
            oldwordaux=oldword;
            newwordaux=newword;
        }else if(response==3){
            size=(size>1? size-1:size);
            oldwordaux = Arrays.copyOfRange(oldword, 0, size);
            newwordaux = Arrays.copyOfRange(newword, 0, size);
        }
    }

    for(int j=0; j<oldword.length; j++){
        if(oldword[j].getText().length()!=0){
            noword=false;
        }
    }

    if(noword){
        return null;
    }else{
        int w=0;
        words = new String[oldword.length*2];
        for(int i=0; i<oldword.length; i++){
                words[i]=oldword[i].getText();
                w=i+1;
            }
        for(int i=0; i<newword.length; i++){
                words[w]=newword[i].getText();
                w++;
        }
        return words;
    }
}
```

I create a new array bigger than the last one when "add" is pressed and I display the new one.

Answer (score 2):

You are using an `ArrayList<JPanel>` as the message. Since the `message` parameter is not `String`, but `Object`, any object is accepted.
In your case, the list contains `JPanel`s which have a `toString()` which is not suitable for your message (it's better suited for debugging).
The object's `toString()` is called and its result is displayed, which is perfectly legal code but most likely not what you want.
Maybe you want to use a [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) to build your string to display.

e.g.

```
 StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
 builder.append("Change: ")
       .append(oldword.getText()) 
       .append("by:")
       .append(newword.getText())
       .toString();
```

EDIT:
It is actually possible to display a `JPanel` in the message, when you use a `Component`, it will be displayed (but when using an `ArrayList`, it won't work):

```
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JTextField oldword = new JTextField(5);
    JTextField newword = new JTextField(5);
    String[] options = new String[] {"Ok", "Cancel", "Add", "Delete"};

    panel.add(new JLabel("Change: "));
    panel.add(oldword);

    panel.add(new JLabel("by:"));
    panel.add(newword);

    JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, panel, "Title",
            JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, options, options[0]);
```

If you want to display multiple Panels, you can put them into a super-Panel and stack them like in [Stack swing elements from top to bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9674774/stack-swing-elements-from-top-to-bottom)

Comment: I'm not sure how it works StringBuilder but the problem is that I not only need to display the text but also to be able to input data. Is that possible with StringBuilder?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain well, I've updated the post with images.

Comment: but what should appear in that dialog, then?

Comment: Change: [box to input which word should be changed] by: [box to input which word is the replacement]

Comment: it is actually possible to display a `Component` in the message. see my updated answer

Comment: But I want to display more than one line. Thank you but I suppose I'll do it with a fixed number of "lines".